# Execute a function after calling gtk.main

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Here is my dilemma: I have a log parser with a pygtk window. After the user opens a file via the dialog, I have a progress bar showing them approximately when the open will be complete (as it can be a lengthy process). I recently added an option to allow the user to specify a file via the command line.

My problem is, since I have to load the file before calling `gtk.main()`. Thus, the window and, more importantly, the progress bar are not displayed until after this lengthy load completes, giving the user no indication.

So, I am hoping there is a way to execute a function after calling `gtk.main()`, or somebody has an alternative approach. Thanks

Comment: See this FAQ entry: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.020.htp

Comment: You can create a thread with the long operation implemented on it and show the progress dialog before call `gtk.main()`. Also, before `gtk.main()`, you maybe need to create a timeout with `gobject.timeout_add` that ask for operation current progress and update the progress bar.

Comment: using `thread`is also a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than beginning the process from the command line as soon as you parse the command line arguments, simply pass the command line argument to your application class (or store in a variable) and process it AFTER you've entered `gtk.main`. That way you can setup your GUI first. Before beginning the process, and every time you increment the progress bar, make sure you let Gtk catch up using something like:

```
 while Gtk.events_pending():
        Gtk.main_iteration()
```

Comment: Ultimately what I did is your code example in a load function that is called directly before `gtk.main()` when command line arguments are called. Thanks.